# Using values from a list as a variable in Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to take some actions for some csv files in my folder,all those files should have same format,except with different IDs;it looks like: Myfile_100_2018-11-26.csv, all those numbers are different(100 means id,the rest numbers are date time);
I have a list object, which contain all ids I want to open, for example my_id=[100,200,300,400]

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import re

allfiles = os.listdir('.')
game_id=[100,200,300,400]
from id in game_id:
     files = [f for f in allfiles if re.search(r'(%s+_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.csv$')%game_id, f)]
```

In my code, I am want to use game_id replace the %s, so that I can loops though all files for ids from 100, 200, 300,400; however I get an error:SyntaxError: invalid syntax for the comma after game_id.

I tried many combination I searched from other questions, but seems didn't work for me, can anyone gives an advice? thanks

Comment: You don't have an opening parenthesis for `)%game_id`

Comment: re.search(r'(%s+_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.csv$'%game_id, f)? this doesn't work

Comment: it is working: [f for f in allfiles if re.search(r'(%s_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.csv$)'%(game_id), f)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass `game_id` to the `re.search` method rather than to the `r'(%s+_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.csv$'` string literal, which is causing trouble.

Then, you have a mismatching opening capturing parenthesis without the closing one, it will cause a regex error.

Besides, the `+` after `%s` might result in unexpected matches: `100`, `1000` and `1000000` game IDs can be returned.

You may use

```
import re
allfiles=['YES_100_1234-22-33.csv', 'NO_1000_1023-22-33.csv', 'no_abc.csv']
game_id=[100,200,300,400]
rx=re.compile(r'(?<!\d)(?:%s)_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.csv$'%"|".join(map(str,game_id)))
# => (?<!\d)(?:100|200|300|400)_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.csv$
files = [f for f in allfiles if rx.search(f)]
print(files) # => ['YES_100_1234-22-33.csv']
```

The regex is formed like

```
rx=re.compile(r'(?<!\d)(?:%s)_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.csv$'%"|".join(map(str,game_id)))
# => (?<!\d)(?:100|200|300|400)_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.csv$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OxNRxa/1).

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit right before the next char matched
- `(?:100|200|300|400)` - `game_id` values joined with an alternation operator
- `_\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` - `_`, 4 digits, `-`, 2 digits, `-`, 2 digits
- `\.csv$` - `.csv` and end of the string.